# Mapping the Right CRM Values (e.g. CLV) to Actual Users (Cookies) After Data Import from CRM to GA

Tags: google-analytics, crm, google-ads-api, data-import

BACKGROUND: The implementation guide for [Importing User Data to create AdWords Remarketing Audiences](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user) describes using the data import feature in Google Analytics to import Customer Lifetime Value (i.e. Silver, Gold or Platinum) from a CRM. The imported file takes the form of a CSV with two columns, one for unique CRM User IDs and one for the Lifetime Value (e.g. Platinum). After creating GA custom dimensions for both values (CRM User ID and Lifetime Value), you create a data set using CRM User ID as the "Key" and Lifetime Value as the "Imported Data". Finally, the GA tracking code must be modified to "set the user scoped dimension to represent the CRM user".

Presumably, when a visitor lands on the site the GA tracker generates and sets a value for the CRM User ID custom dimension, and the data set schema which defines the key and imported data proceeds to associate that CRM User ID with a Lifetime Value (e.g. Platinum).

QUESTION: Since the Lifetime Values are specific to the CRM User IDs that they are associated with at the time of import, shouldn't the mapping of CRM User ID to Lifetime Value be invalid within the GA environment (or "after the import")? For example, when a new visitor hits the site, the tracking code must assign a *brand new* CRM User ID (ID = "123") because that visitor's cookie won't have an existing ID value. So GA refers to the data set schema's "Key" for that user's ID ("123") and assigns a Lifetime Value of "Platinum" because "123" is mapped to "Platinum". But "123" was the unique CRM ID for a user who *truly* had a "Platinum" Lifetime Value, and now we've reassigned both that user's ID and Lifetime Value to a random site visitor. Am I misunderstanding how this works? Ultimately, I'd like to create AdWords remarketing lists based on CRM attributes, but the underlying logic of this data import feature is hard to follow.